# How to get touch events below empty view of viewpager in android

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-camera

[How to make android camera mode changing view?The camera preview should be displayed even though user opened camera mode.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nY1r3.png) If you've tried changing camera shooting mode or different filters, in most android phones, a user needs to swipe right or left for opening camera mode page with some black transparency on top of camera preview. I tried with viewpager without putting fragments but only with views. I put camera mode view for 1 page of viewpager and for second just empty view, because if user swipes to empty view it should only show camera preview. But I can not get touch events in camera, below empty view of viewpager.

Comment: you'd better to control the touch and swipe events in camera preview. And, when a user swipe camera privew, then the app shows the camera mode View with animation.